# My windows 10 hp laptop is shutting down abnormally every day at a particular time

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I am using latest version of windows 10. It is an HP laptop. 
My problem is that every day at a particular time(evening) my laptop shutdowns automatically while I was using it. I checked my battery percentage it is above 50% when this happened. I don't know where is the problem. I did not used any scheduler to shut down the laptop.
Please help me to fix my laptop.

Comment: Open Reliability Monitor (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance) . What errors do you see there?

Comment: Critical events windows was not properly shut down

Comment: Try updating BIOS, Chipset and then all remaining drivers to see if driver updates help.

Comment: @John Thanks, I will do it. Another important problem in my laptop is that I was getting wrong battery percentage since a week. Is this realted to the present problem?

Comment: Wrong battery percentage may indicate the need for an updated power driver